# Lazy Loading simple type nullable properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading

Is it possible to implement a lazy loading of a simple type property?

In some cases I do have classes that have rarely used properties. 
Because of that, I don't want EF to select their values on the loading process. I wish to explicitly 'ask' for the loading of those values.

So far, I've been placing those properties on a separate class, 1-to-1 with the main class, and then Lazy loading that secondary class (that only holds the less used properties). But it really would be nicer to place all properties on the same class without the burden of loading them each and every time.

For example:

```
public class User {
    [Key]
    public int IDUser { get; set; }
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Login { get; set; }
    [StringLength(60)]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birth { get; set; }
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    //Less used properties (to be Lazy-loaded):

    public virtual string Address { get; set; }
    public virtual int? Floor { get; set; }        
    public virtual int? DeskNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual string SkillsDefinition { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Separate class is on the only solution for what you want to do.

Comment: NHibernate supports this, EF doesn't. As CodeNotFound says: use a separate class, maybe in a *table splitting* arrangement.